# Creating MS Project based on Start +X days

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I am trying to create a draft project plan in MS Project, but the request from my Director is to exclude all dates.

I cannot work out how to do this or if it is even possible in MS Project.

Therefore rather than a project starting on 15th Nov, I would like to create one starting on Day 0, then for events after this is listed as something like 'Start +40 days' instead of 20th December, so a task which takes 2 days would end on something like 'Start +42 days' or 'T+42 days' (borrowing from NASA) or something similar.

Is this possible please and how would I do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Project does need calendar dates in order to create a schedule. However, you can format the Gantt chart to show the timescale as a reference to the start of the project.

To do this, double-click the timescale to bring up the format options and change the label on the top/middle/bottom tiers as desired.

[image: format Gantt timescale]